# Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I swapped from `babel-preset-es2015` to `babel-preset-env` and made the related changes in other places:

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

But now I'm getting the error:

> Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'

when I'm running a webworker that transpiles code in the following way:

**ww.bundle.js** (path/to/runner.js --export-to--> path/to/ww.js --browserify-bundled--> ww.bundle.js):

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
const env = require('babel-preset-env');

const esFive = babel.transform(testCode, { presets: [env] }).code;
```

Before, I had the following:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
const es2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');

const esFive = babel.transform(testCode, { presets: [es2015] }).code;
```

and it worked fine.

I believe the preset needed to be explicitly imported because `ww.bundle.js` couldn't locate `.babelrc` in the `/` directory.

If I try simply with:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');

const esFive = babel.transform(testCode, { presets: ['env'] }).code;
```

I once again get the error message from my earlier troubles:

> Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/"